# Escribir en un fichero desde consola

Tags: java, archivo, scanner, java-util-scanner, filewriter

estoy haciendo un **traductor** para un proyecto y necesito ***manipular ficheros.***
El traductor tiene un diccionario en **español** y otro en **inglés** a los que les **añado *por defecto 100 palabras*** que tengo en un archivo de texto llamado **texto.txt**
Luego hay un método que es el que usa el usuario final con el que puede añadir palabras a mano con un `Scanner`, es este:

```
/**
     * Añade palabras a los diccionarios.
     * @param reader
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void addPalabraScanner(Scanner reader) throws IOException{

    String espanol, ingles, escape;
    do {
        System.out.print("Palabra espanol: ");
        espanol = reader.next();

        System.out.print("Palabra ingles: ");
        ingles = reader.next();

//añade las palabras insertadas por teclado a ambos diccionarios
        addPalabras(espanol, ingles);
        System.out.println("Escriba FIN si desea dejar de insertar palabras.");
        escape = reader.next().toLowerCase();
    } while(!escape.toLowerCase().equals("fin"));
}
```

El método con el que ***añado palabras*** desde el fichero es el siguiente:

```
/**
     * Anade palabras desde un fichero.
     * @param ruta es la ruta del fichero.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addPalabrasFichero(String ruta) throws IOException {

    FileReader fichero = new FileReader(ruta);
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fichero);

    String linea = buffer.readLine();

    //significado[] toma la palabra en espanol e ingles
    //palabra[] toma cada palabra de significado[]
    String [] significado,palabra;
    int posicion=0;

    while(linea != null) {

        //se guarda la linea hasta el salto de linea
        significado = linea.split("\n");

        //se anaden las palabras mediante el limitador establecido
        palabra = significado[posicion].split("\t");
        addPalabras(palabra[posicion+1], palabra[posicion]);

        linea = buffer.readLine();
    }
}
```

**El problema viene ahora:**
Mi objetivo es que todas las ***palabras que le voy pasando por teclado*** las *añada a un fichero llamado **textoSalida.txt*** pero soy incapaz de conseguirlo; este es el método que tengo:

```
/**
     * Añade las palabras insertadas por teclado a un fichero.
     * @param ruta es la ruta del archivo
     * @param espanol es la palabra en español a añadir
     * @param ingles es la palabra en ingles a añadir
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void ficheroDiccionario(String ruta, String espanol, String ingles) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter(ruta);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String texto= buffer.readLine();

        if(texto==null) {
            fichero.write(ingles);
            fichero.write(" ");
            fichero.write(espanol);
        }

    fichero.close();
}
```

El método anterior está basado en los apuntes que tenemos y no funciona, **el archivo de texto no se rellena nunca**. ¿Alguien puede decirme cómo resolverlo?

Answer (score 1):

La condición para escribir en un fichero está mal. Has puesto:

```
if (texto == null) {
    fichero.write(ingles);
    fichero.write(" ");
    fichero.write(espanol);
}
```

Esto implica que se intentará escribir únicamente cuando el texto leído sea nulo, es decir, que cuando escribas algo en consola, nunca se va a intentar escribir en el fichero.

Cambia la condición por lo siguiente:

```
if (texto != null) {/* ESCRIBIR EN FICHERO */}
```

De todas formas, te sugiero separar la funcionalidad en clases distintas.
Es decir, lee de consola en una clase `Consola`, y pasa el texto leído a un objeto de una hipotética clase `Escritor` que escriba en un fichero mediante un método que podría ser `escribir(String nombreFichero, String palabraEspañol, String palabraInglés)`, que **no haga uso de un reader ni de System.in**.

Solo es una recomendación, pero el error es por una condición contraria a lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: Al final descubrí cómo hacerlo @Eequiis ,acabo de publicarlo como respuesta; de todas formas, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Era algo tan simple como esto:

```
/**
     * Añade las palabras insertadas por teclado a un fichero.
     * @param espanol es la palabra en español a añadir
     * @param ingles es la palabra en ingles a añadir
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addPalabraToFichero( String espanol, String ingles) throws IOException {

    FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\diccionario.txt", true);
    PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(fichero);

    salida.print(ingles);
    salida.print(" ");
    salida.println(espanol);
    salida.close();
}
```